# Read multiple files continuously and simultaneously

Tags: python

I am trying to write a program which reads the content of plain text files continuously and appends the lines content to a list.

It looks like this:

```py
data = []
file_position = 0

while True:
    with open('test.txt', 'r') as f:
        f.seek(file_position) 
        for line in f:
            data.append(int(line))
        file_position = f.tell()

        if sys.stdin in select.select([sys.stdin], [], [], 0)[0]:
            line = input()
            break
```

The last `if` statement is to break out of the `while` loop by pressing enter.

Now what I want to achieve would be to read another text file, say `test2.txt`, also in real-time and append its lines to say `data2 = []`. And this process should happen simultaneously to the process above. So my program should read line 1, for example, of both files at the same time and append its content to the respective list, then go to line 2 of each file and so on.

What would be the approach to do that?

Answer (score 2):

I think you have 3 options

1. async IO https://pypi.org/project/aiofile/
2. threads and read each file in a different thread, then if you want to process it somehow you probably do not want to use lists but deque or Queue
3. use select to read from each fd when it's ready to be read, but you would need to do something about your "wait for 'enter' to terminate"

Comment: Thanks. I've never heard of deque or Queue. Why would I use that instead of lists? I'll look into your suggestions!

Comment: It's all about memory access, with threads you can't tell what is running when, so if you are removing something from the list and the same moment you are adding to it, there could be ( and according to murphy's law will be ) a problem. deque or Queue are thread safe ( the internally use locks) so you do not have to

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like this:

```
from threading import Thread

def copy_file_func(in_file_name, out_file_name)
    with open(file_name) as f:
        with open("out.txt", "w") as f1:
            for line in f:
                if sys.stdin in select.select([sys.stdin], [], [], 0)[0]:
                    line = input()
                    break
                f1.write(line)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Thread(target = copy_file_func, kwargs={'in_file_name': 'first.txt', 'out_file_name': 'first_out.txt'}).start()
```

But writing this in bash may go faster if time it important to you

Comment: Hey thanks for the answer. Could you maybe explain a bit what is going on in your code, I am kind of a newbie.